# Why does my plot_ly volcano plot not respond to certain yaxis arguments?

Tags: r, plotly, bioinformatics

I'm trying to plot a differential gene expression volcano plot with plot_ly to make it interactive. I have a dataframe with 4 columns: log2FoldChange, padj, GeneName, group. I want to remove ticks from the y axis to make it more visibly appealing and i want to remove the zeroline. However, the plot doesn't respond to any of the arguments i add to do this. My question is whether the arguments are wrong or if there is something wrong with the environment.

I used the following code:

```
library("gridExtra")
library("plotly")
#Make DESeq results into a workable dataframe
plot_data <- data.frame(
  log2FoldChange = de_result_wt_gene$log2FoldChange,
  padj = de_result_wt_gene$padj,
  GeneName = de_result_wt_gene$GeneName
) 

#Want to divide genes into groups based on position in the volcano plot
plot_data["group"] <- "Not Significant"

plot_data[which(-log10(plot_data['padj']) > -log10(0.1) & abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) < 1 & abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) > -1 ),"group"] <- "Significant"

plot_data[which(-log10(plot_data['padj']) < -log10(0.1) & abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) > 1 | abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) < -1 ),"group"] <- "Log 2 fold change"

plot_data[which(-log10(plot_data['padj']) > -log10(0.1) & abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) > 1 | abs(plot_data['log2FoldChange']) < -1 ),"group"] <- "Log 2 fold change & Significant"

#Want the top differentially expressed genes
top_peaks <- plot_data[with(plot_data, order(log2FoldChange, padj)),][1:5,]
top_peaks <- rbind(top_peaks, plot_data[with(plot_data, order(-log2FoldChange, padj)),][1:5,])

#The interactive annotation when you hover over a gene
a <- list()
for (i in seq_len(nrow(top_peaks))) {
  m <- top_peaks[i, ]
  a[[i]] <- list(
    x = m[["log2FoldChange"]],
    y = -log10(m[["padj"]]),
    text = m[["GeneName"]],
    xref = "x",
    yref = "y",
    showarrow = TRUE,
    arrowhead = 0.5,
    ax = 20,
    ay = -40
  )
}

#Threshold lines 
line1 <- list(type = "line", y0 = 0, y1 = 1, yref = "paper", x0 = -1, x1 = -1, line = list(color = "black", dash = "dot"))
line2 <- list(type = "line", y0 = 0, y1 = 1, yref = "paper", x0 = 1, x1 = 1, line = list(color = "black", dash = "dot"))
line3 <- list(type = "line", y0 = -log10(0.1), y1 = -log10(0.1), x0 = 0, x1 = 1, xref = "paper", line = list(color = "black", dash = "dot"))

p <- plot_ly(data = plot_data, x = ~log2FoldChange, y = ~-log10(padj), text = ~GeneName, mode = "markers", color = ~group, type = 'scatter') |> 
  layout(title = "gene vs WT", annotations = a, shapes = list(line1, line2, line3), yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE, range=list(0, 30), ntick= 3), xaxis = list(range=list(-8, 8)))
  

p
```

I've also tried: showline = FALSE, showline = F, zeroline = F, both at the same time, shouldn't make a difference... and it didn't. I've loaded more libraries for earlier on in the code:

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(BiocManager)
library(DESeq2)
library(ggrepel)
library(EnhancedVolcano)
library(eulerr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
```

Comment: I think what you're really looking for is on the *x-axis*.  Give it a whirl: `xaxis = list(zeroline = F)`. If that's not what you're looking for, I'm going to need you to make your question reproducible to give you the help you're looking for. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).